# what is angle at baseline center point of an oblique triangle cut in half, from apex to baseline center?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

For an oblique triangle with points LTR where L is lower left, T top (apex), and R lower right:

Let C be the exact center point of baseline LR.

If imaginary line goes from point T down to point C, then what is angle TCR?
The lengths of triangle's sides are known:  LT LR TR
The triangle's 3 angles at L, T, R can be derived using Law of Cosines.

But how to get angle TCR?

Answer (score 0):

The law of cosines/ [Stewart's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart's_theorem) gives:
$$ TC^2 = \frac{2\, TL^2+2\,TR^2-LR^2}{4} $$
hence you may find $\cos(\widehat{TCR})$ through the law of cosines, too.